# Example of addmargin - Error

Tags: errors, margins

I'm trying to learn how to use addmargin command. To do this I wrote the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\listfiles


\begin{document}

\begin{addmargin}[-1cm]{-3cm}
Blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{addmargin}

\end{document}
```

But LaTeX gives me the error:

! LaTeX Error: Environment addmargin undefined.

How can I fix it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: As far as I know `addmargin` is a KOMA command (i.e. in documentclasses like `scrarctl`).

Comment: take a look on the `changepage` package

Comment: Hello @TeXnician, I solved with \documentclass{scrreprt}. Thank you for your good comment.

Comment: You can use it with scrextend.

Comment: Hi @Johannes_B, your comment is very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addmargin` is an environment defined by KOMA Script, so you have to use a a KOMA class to use it (e.g. `scrartcl`). KOMA script makes some features available to standard classes as well (package `scrextend`), so if you wanted to go with a standar class you could use this package.

But basically your example would look like:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\listfiles


\begin{document}

\begin{addmargin}[-1cm]{-3cm}
Blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{addmargin}

\end{document}
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the difference between scrartcl and scrreprt please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi The one replaces `article` the other `report` (so the former does not have e.g. chapters, the second has).

Comment: Excellent explanation @TeXnician.

Comment: Scrextend with standard classes

Comment: @Johannes_B Right, I forgot about that package. I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

with the `changepage` package :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\listfiles
\usepackage{changepage}



\begin{document}

Blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa


\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-3cm}
Blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @flav, my goal is to learn how to use addmargin, but thank you for your reply.